# Custom key for every row from Excel while converting to JSON

Tags: json, excel, pandas

How to set user defined key to JSON values which will be added from Excel file?
For example, Excel file is something like this:
I am using pandas to convert  this excel to json.
I need to set custom key for "Ball", "show", etc. Is there a way to ask user for key for every value from the Excel file?

```
 -------------------------------
    | EN        | DE         | RU |
    ------------+------------+-----
    | Ball      | Ball       | AA |
    | Snow      | Schnee     | BB |
    | Elephant  | Elephant   | CC |
    | Woman     | Frau       | DD |
    | Potato    | Kartoffeln | EE |
    | Tomato    | F          | FF |
    | Carrot    | G          | GG |
    -------------------------------
```

Just to clarify, I want something like this:

```
"Please insert key for "Ball" "
 - myBallKey (user input)
"Please insert key for "Snow" "
 - myKeyForSnow (user input)
```

And for all values from 'en' column respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using concat, to exclude 'new_key' column, try something like this:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns != 'new_key']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood correctly, you would have another column in your excel that is called custom_key for example?

So to take in the custom keys you would need a loop like this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[index, 'new_key'] = input('Please enter the new key: ')
```

Assuming you do that, you should be able do something like the following:

```
df = df.set_index('custom_key')
```

Which will set that columns values to the rows index.

You could then use the following to get JSON with those index values as keys:

```
df.to_json(orient='index')
```

Comment: no I want to enable user to choose key. For example, he should get message: "Please set key for "Ball", and then he should type it, then for another one, until there is no more values to read from excel file.

Comment: If you want something at read time I don't think its possible.. But you could do it after the read with a loop. Something like: for index, row in df.iterrows(): df.at[index, 'key'] = input(f'Please provide a key for {df['the_column you need a key for']}: )

Comment: Hmm, it's a bit tricky, because I need to loop it like for i in rows set index at i, i+i, etc...
I load data as padas.readExcel(path) and then I set index like myDf.setIndex(index), but this time, index will contain different user inserted values.

Comment: Take a look at the edited answer above. It shows how you can take in custom input and set it as the index

Comment: you did not understand correctly. I do not have column with key. I should use keys which user inputs for every value. The thing is that I am not sure if I can set index for every value separately. Currently, I am using 'en' column for index.
I want something like this:
Please insert key for "Ball":
- ballKey (user input)
Please insert key for "Snow":
- myKeyForSnow (user input)
For all values respectively.

Comment: My edited answer does exactly that for you. But it will set the values in a column that you then use to create the indexes. Please try running the for loop I've provided

Comment: I got error
   pd.DataFrame.at[index, 'new_key'] = input('Please enter the new key: ')
TypeError: 'property' object does not support item assignment

Comment: You're initializing a new dataframe by doing pd.DataFrame(). Where I put "df" you should put the name of the variable containing your dataframe

Comment: I got this
 "new_key":{
     "SSS": "Ball",
    "Pooo":"Snow",
    "Stranje":"Elephant"
  }, but I don't need this "new_key" part, these values should be added to an existing JSON localisation file which contains columns with languages.
I need this column for key only, it shouldn't be written in JSON file as column.

Comment: Please read the rest of my answer.. I cover how you can make this part of your json.

Comment: Will it work if I am concatenating these values to an existing JSON file? I am asking you, because I am concatenating these values to an existing JSON file using pandas concat.